# Howto have maven surefire execute JUnit and TestNG test properly?

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng, jnario

Since a while it is possible to configure maven surefire to execute jUnit tests and testNG tests in one build. I won't expand on the reasons why I'm doing that (ok, hint: testNG is our standard framework but some frameworks like [jnario](http://jnario.org/) require jUnit).

The general way to do it is to configure the surefire plugin like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

[(taken from here)](http://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/mixing-testng-and-junit-tests-in-one-maven-module-2013-edition/)

This works quite well, jUnit tests and testNG tests get executed.

BUT - now I see that testNG tries to execute the jUnit tests too (and maybe vice-versa) - with no success, of course, because it won't see any of its annotations, but it looks like it re-marks the tests to "passed"... anyway, some reporting tools don't show test fails in jUnit tests anymore unless I comment the second dependency entry.

Is there any better way to configure surefire so that tests from both frameworks are executed ONLY by their test runners?

Comment: Cross-posted on the Maven-Users-List: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-surefire-selecting-providers-td5764817.html

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem as you. Zero results in TestNG reports but looks like tests were runned. 
Finally get this work on two separate executions of `maven-surefire-plugin`

1. First remove the `dependencies` section from plugin.

   - otherwise if you use `<testNGArtifactName>` (and we'll need it) tests will be executed by TestNG anyway and will fail on `java.lang.NullPointerException`
2. Have some separation of TestNG tests and JUnit tests. In our case NG test class names ends with `TestNg`
3. skip default execution
4. define two `<executions>` like below:

```xml
<plugin>
    <!-- configured to work with JUnit and TestNg in same project separatelly -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>              
    <configuration>
        <!-- whatever you need... -->
        <!-- skip the default execution, we have separate for Ng and for JUnit -->
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>TestNg-execution</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- overwrite skip from default config -->
                <skip>false</skip>
                <includes>
                    <include>%regex[.*TestNg.*]</include>
                </includes>
                <!-- used to skip JUnit profider -->
                <junitArtifactName>dev:null</junitArtifactName>
                <!-- to continue on next execution in case of failures here -->
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>JUnit-execution</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>

                <skip>false</skip>
                <!-- used to skip TestNg profider -->
                <testNGArtifactName>dev:null</testNGArtifactName>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>%regex[.*TestNg.*]</exclude>                               
                </excludes>
            </configuration>                    
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Tested with:

```xml
<junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
<maven-surefire-plugin-version>2.16</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
<org.testng-version>6.8.7</org.testng-version>
```

This configuration is the marge of ideas from:
[Running TestNG-, JUnit3- and JUnit4-tests with Maven Surefire in one run](http://rolf-engelhard.de/2011/07/running-testng-junit3-and-junit4-tests-with-maven-surefire-in-one-run/),
[your SUREFIRE bug report](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-1019),
[surefire plugin configuration](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: We're not doing this yet, but I'm saving this answer for when we get there.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it myself, but you could try to configure two [different executions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) of the maven-surefire-plugin and configure one of these executions to only run JUnit tests and the other to only run testNG tests. To differentiate between JUnit und testNG tests you should either put the tests in different directories or use a distinguishable name scheme and configure each of the executions with suitable [inclusion and exclusion patterns](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

In theory this should work :)

Comment: I can't pull the `<dependencies>` element into the execution. If I could, then it would really be *the* solution, one execution limited to jUnit, the other one to TestNG :(

Comment: You got me wrong. I meant to have both <dependencies> as in the original question. But you could configure different includes/excludes, that one execution would only find JUnit tests and the other one would only find testNG tests. This way the unwanted tests are filtered out by surefire and won't be passed to the  testing frameworks.

Comment: Ah. Yes, I tried that too (and it went even worse) TestNG get's activated for all executions and the build fails if one execution has no test to run (yes, there's a property...) - it looks as if I found a bug, someone from the maven users mailing list strongly encouraged me to [report an issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-1019). +1 for answer & help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the **Running TestNG and JUnit Tests** section at the bottom of [this](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) page was there in 2013, but setting `junit=false` in the `surefire-testng` provider seems to answer your question now.